# Install iOS simulator 16.5?

Tags: ios, xcode14.3

Xcode 14.3.1 only showing OS 16.4 in-built option. To validate some crash we need to run code on Simulator 16.5 version. Xcode 15 beta have option to install OS 17.0 version.
Does any know how to install 16.5 OS version Simulator

Downloading 16.5 Simulator version with Xcode 14.3.1.
Not sure if xcode 15 beta gives option to install OS 16.5 or not.

Comment: To validate a crash you should really run on a real device with iOS 16.5

Comment: I need 16.6 but can't find it. Is Microsoft trying to sell us some AppCenter? AppCenter has a 16.6 test bench...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like apple isn't planning to release a simulator for 16.5.x for some reason.. It basically says apple doesn't make simulators for every release, and 16.5 is just one of those that isn't going to have a simulator.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731199

It's a bit annoying as anything the reviewers see [as a problem] could be a iOS version issue or could be build/code related, and it's not possible to determine which is to blame. I guess the only solution is to wait until they come out with a new iOS version? or test with physical phones running 16.5

Comment: The physical devices are even more limited because if you update then there is no way to rollback the iOS version...